# Find specific value in specific column of csv file in python

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I need to extract the specified characters in the specified column in the csv file,I got an error saying "TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str"

my csv file

```
name,age,sex
li,26,M
mu,30,F
```

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import glob
for i in glob.glob('H:\\1\\*.csv'):
    result_1=pd.read_csv(i,encoding="utf-8",dtype=object)
    SubNetwork_list=list(result_1.groupby(["name"]))
    for SubNetwork in SubNetwork_list:
        SubNetwork_pd=pd.DataFrame(SubNetwork["li"])
        SubNetwork_pd.to_csv("H:\\2\\li.csv",encoding="utf-8",
                         header=True,index=False,mode='a')
```

console error

```
SubNetwork_pd=pd.DataFrame(SubNetwork['li'])
TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Answer (score 0):

When iterating over a groupby, each element of that iterator is a tuple of `(group_name, group_dataframe)`.

So to iterate over a groupby, you need to do something like this:

```
    SubNetwork_list=list(result_1.groupby(["name"]))
    for SubNetwork_name, SubNetwork in SubNetwork_list:
```

This unpacks the tuple.

More information: [Docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.__iter__.html#pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.__iter__)

PS: You don't need to call `list()` on the groupby object. You can iterate over it without doing that, and it's faster.

Comment: `    raise KeyError(key) from err
KeyError: 'li'`

Comment: i get an error，can you provide the full code

Comment: I can't provide the full code - you haven't posted a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples). The issue you're facing is caused by there being no 'li' column present in your input CSV. See [Indexing and selecting data tutorial](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#different-choices-for-indexing) and [DataFrame.set_index()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) for how to do what you want.